# Read private key from PFX file, decrypt the ciphertext with that private key

Tags: java, encryption, rsa, bouncycastle

I trying to get the private key from password protected PFX file, and do the decryption with the help of the extracted private key.Tried the following code, but getting the `NullPointerException`.

```
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
    PEMParser pemParser = new PEMParser(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("..//pfx//pfx//BC_6.pfx")));
    PEMEncryptedKeyPair encryptedKeyPair = (PEMEncryptedKeyPair) pemParser.readObject();
    PEMDecryptorProvider decryptorProvider = new JcePEMDecryptorProviderBuilder().build("test123".toCharArray());
    PEMKeyPair pemKeyPair = encryptedKeyPair.decryptKeyPair(decryptorProvider);

    JcaPEMKeyConverter converter = new JcaPEMKeyConverter().setProvider("BC");
    System.out.println(" Private Key --->  "+converter.getPrivateKey(pemKeyPair.getPrivateKeyInfo()));
```

Output is,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.test.obfuscate.EncryptionUtil.main(EncryptionUtil.java:40)
```

Please suggest on this, stuck with this from past one week. Tried different posts from StackOverflow.

Comment: Which line is responsible for the NPE you get?

Comment: Getting NPE at "PEMKeyPair pemKeyPair = encryptedKeyPair.decryptKeyPair(decryptorProvider);" line

Comment: A PFX aka PKCS12 file is **not PEM format** (as you can see by looking at it) and cannot be read by the BC routines that handle (some) PEM formats. However both standard Java (JCE) and BC _can_ handle PKCS12 as a _keystore_. Call `KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12" [,provider])` and use the resulting object to load the PFX file, then obtain the key from the object, all as explained in the javadoc for `KeyStore`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PEMParser pemParser = new PEMParser(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("..//pfx//pfx//BC_6.pfx")));`

Are you trying to read the PFX file as a PEM file?? The PFX file is effectively PKCS12 keystore.

So (typing from my head, please don't mind small typos / syntax errors)

```
InputStream in = ...
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
ks.load(in);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(PEMEncryptedKeyPair) pemParser.readObject()
```

returns `null`, therefore

`encryptedKeyPair` is `null` and you cannot call its methods. Make sure you do one or more of the following:

- make sure you correctly read the value, so it is not `null`
- only call the method of the object if it is different from `null`
- `try`-`catch` to handle exceptions

Comment: How do you know that returned null? Perhaps instead the next statement returned null. Also, your answer is very generic.